# Caffe convert_imageset: symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I used caffe to train my CNN.When I transfered my data to the lmdb format using the tool `'convert_imageset'`, it report an error:

> ```
> /convert_imageset: symbol lookup error: ../../build/tools/convert_imageset: undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe16ReadImageToDatumERKSsiiiiibS1_PNS_5DatumE
> ```

How could I solve it??

Answer (score 2):

The symbol you are missing is the function:

```
caffe::ReadImageToDatum(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, int, int, int, bool, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, caffe::Datum*)
```

(You can use [`c++filt`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) shell utility to recover this from the symbol you got in your error message)

The missing function is declared in `io.hpp` file, but its implementation in `io.cpp` is conditioned on `USE_OPENCV` directive (see [BVLC/caffe issue #5329](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5329)).

Re-build your caffe with [`USE_OPENCV := 1`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile.config.example#L11) in `'Makefile.config'`.